# How to find out where the performance leak is?

Tags: asp.net, performance

I have an self-build asp.net page, ([link](http://www.repair-your-iphone.de)), and on my own localhost-server it runs very fast.
But when I have uploaded it to my rent server (Win08Server, 3GB Ram, 3GhZ...) it goes very very slow (3-5 second a site-switch).

hot to find out what programm is disturbing or where I have a leak?

(the most of the content is static, only a 2 database querys at the beginning!!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08%28VS.71%29.aspx) (`<trace enabled ="true" pageOutput ="true" />` in web.config) to trace the flow and find the bottlenecks.
Refer to [this](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Tracing-ASP.NET.aspx) article for the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checkout the other sites hosted on the same server are they slow too...

I think the issue is with the server not with your code, as you are saying it only has two queries at the home page.

If other sites are responding fast then your code has to be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be an authentication issue?  If you are using a web host perhaps their AD server is under load OR you have a strange group lookup which takes a few seconds to set the security context of your queries?

I still would do what @Li0liQ recommends however, trace first, don't do psychic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

What are your visitor numbers? If don you have many concurrent you could these strategies:

- Try "stress testing" and "load testing" on your local machine (and if possible before every deployment). (I find Grinder easy to learn and to use)
- Use a profiler like DotTrace (Jetbrains) or the one from Redgate - both have Trial Licenses